# Getting BUILD FAILED (macOS 13.2.1 on arm64 using ruby-build 20231114) using M2 Macbook

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, ruby-build

I am currently on ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [arm64-darwin22]. I am trying to install Ruby 3.2.2 on Macbook Ventura 13.2.1. These are the steps I've followed:

1. `brew install ruby-build`
2. `brew install rbenv`
3. `rbenv init`
4. `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc`
5. `brew upgrade ruby-build`
6. `rbenv install 3.2.2 --verbose`

Then I get this error message:

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Loading the Ruby yaml extension failed (linked to incompatible /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/libruby.3.0.dylib - /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/psych-5.1.1.1/lib/psych.bundle)
```

I did install libyaml and psych, but I am still getting the message above.

Comment: You need to provide the actual build errors. Most likely you're missing either the Xcode CLI components or other dependencies, but without the actual error logs people would just be guessing.

Comment: Even with the new information, you're not providing sufficient error context. Chances are that your build process can't find the installed libraries such as libyaml, which is often an issue with *PATH*, one of the compiler variables, or pkg-config. Ruby 3.x also has issues compiling against other macOS libraries such as LibreSSL or older/newer versions of OpenSSL, so there may be other issues that you're masking here.